# magento admin - customize add new customer form

Tags: magento

I have to put validation for the Date Of Birth field in add new customer form in magento admin. After the google research I found how to add the validation. I have create a new `dateofbirth.js` file and include it in the page. `dateofbirth.js` contains -

```
if(Validation) {
   Validation.addAllThese ([
    ['validate-dob',
     'DOB cannot be in the future', 
      function (v) {

     }]
  ])};
```

and I know this depends on the field having a class name as "validate-dob". The problem is how should I add the class to "Date of Birth" field. I don't have any idea. I tried to find the core files but didn't find the code.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These fields are defined in `eav_attribute` table. You have to manually add the class name in `frontend_class` column.